# Postback is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown in which I am adding list items dynamically. I set autopostback to true, but nothing seems to happen when I select an item in dropdown.

Mark Up

```
`<asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="restaurant_city_con" CssClass="selectboxindex"></asp:DropDownList>`
```

Code Behind

```
`if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    addStates();
    showData();
    dashboardPageFunction();
    ordersPageFunction();
    reportsPageFunction();
    categoriesPageFunction();
    menuPageFunction();
    offersPageFunction();
    bookingPageFunction();
}
else
{
    addCities();
    addZipCode();
}`
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

Comment: you need to add a selectedindexchanged event as well

Comment: have you tried debugging with a breakpoint in the selectedindexchanged event?

Comment: yeah I used breakpoints but when i select an item in dropdown nothing happens. it seems like I am using Select tag of html.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="restaurant_city_con" 
    CssClass="selectboxindex" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="restaurant_city_con_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void restaurant_city_con_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
                                                        EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with selected item here
    Label1.Text = "You selected " + restaurant_city_con.SelectedItem.Text +
                 " with a value of " + restaurant_city_con.SelectedItem.Value +
                 ".";
}
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.restaurantdashboard_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'restaurant_city_con_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'restaurant_city_con_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.restaurantdashboard_aspx'